# On finding $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{a^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following proof from a while back of the simple $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x}{a^x}$, where $a>1$, but can't remember how a specific part of it works anymore for the life of me. Now thinking it's not a solution at all.

Set $a^x=(1+p)^x$, with $p>0$. Expanding the binomial expression, we get:

$$0<(1+p)^x<\dfrac{x}{1+xp+\frac{x(x-1)}{2}\cdot p^2}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+p+\frac{x-1}{2}\cdot p^2},$$
which clearly goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity.

As a result, since $a^x=(1+p)^x$, $a$ must also go to zero, as per the squeeze theorem. Does the following part make sense? And how?

$$0<(1+p)^x<\dfrac{x}{1+xp+\frac{x(x-1)}{2}\cdot p^2}$$

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer a derivative-free proof.

Comment: You write $a=(1+p)^n$ and start letting $n\to\infty$. But $a$ is fixed. And it is $x$ which tends to $\infty$. So everything you've written is confusing.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it and changed all $n$ to $x$.

Comment: There’s definitely something wrong. If I set $p = 1$, then $(1+p)^x = 2^x$ clearly goes to infinity as $x$ approaches to infinity. But you’re saying that $(1+p)^x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: What is $n$ ?...

Comment: "$0<(1+p)^x<\dfrac{x}{1+xp+\frac{x(x-1)}{2}\cdot p^2}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+p+\frac{x-1}{2}\cdot p^2},$"  This is obviously nonsense and I have no idea why you are claiming it from half memory when it is obviously false..... But if $x$ is an integer and $x> 2$ then $(1+p)^x =1 + px + \frac {x(x+1)}2p^2+ ......+{x \choose k} p^k + ..... + p^x > 1 + px + \frac {x(x+1)}2p^2$ is true.... and from *there* $\frac x{(1+p)^x}=\frac x{1 + px + \frac {x(x+1)}2p^2 + ...... + {x \choose k} p^k + ..... + p^x}< \frac x{1 + px + \frac {x(x+1)}2p^2}=\frac 1{\frac 1x+p +\frac{x+1}2p^2}<\frac 1{\frac{x+1}2p^2}$

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to write:
$$
0 < \frac{x}{a^x} = \frac{x}{(1+p)^x} < \frac{x}{1+xp+\frac{x(x-1)}{2} p^2}
$$

Comment: Ah.. great. And is that a valid expansion of the binomial expression?

Comment: @Orm No. In the last term on the right's denominator you have *a part* of the binomial expression. Since the whole binomial expression is non-negative, that part is less than $\;(1+p)^x\;$ and then the inequality...

Comment: If $x$ is an integer larger than 2, then, as @DonAntonio says, you have *part* of the binomial expansion, and the inequality holds because the rest of the expansion is positive.  If $x$ is a noninteger larger than 2, the inequality is also correct.  But you said you wanted a "derivative free" proof.  I'm not sure how to verity the inequality for noninteger $x$ without using derivatives.

Comment: I suppose you could avoid the noninteger issue by writing $x = n + r$, where $n$ is an integer and $0 \le r < 1$.  Then use $(1+p)^x > (1+p)^n > 1 + np + n(n-1)/2 p^2$ by the binomial expansion.

Comment: @DanVelleman You'd still need to see that $a^x$ is increasing in $x$. So it depends on the definition of $a^x$; if a calculus-free definition is used I'd find it tedious to prove that it's incresing.

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb Z; x> 2$ then the binomial exapansion is $(1+p)^x = \sum_{k=0}^x {x\choose k}x^k$.  As each term ${x\choose k}x^k > 0$ we have $(1+p)^x=\sum_{k=0}^x {x\choose k}x^k>\sum_{k=0}^{\color{blue}{2}}{x\choose k}x^k=1+ px +\frac{x(x+1)}2p^2$. And therefore $\frac 1{a^x}=\frac 1{(1+p)^x}< \frac 1{1+ px +\frac{x(x+1)}2p^2}$ and therefore $\frac x{a^x}< \frac x{1+ px +\frac{x(x+1)}2p^2}$

Comment: If we define $a^x:x\in \mathbb R$ as $\sup\{a^q;q\in \mathbb Q; q\le x\}$ and define $a^q;q\in \mathbb Q$ as: if $q=\frac mn,m,n\in \mathbb Z;n\ge 1$ then $a^q=\sqrt[n]{a}^m$ the we can prove $a^x$ is increasing by noting $\frac mn < \frac jk\iff mk < jn$ and so $a^{\frac mn}=\sqrt[n]{a}^m=\sqrt[nk]{a}^{mk}<\sqrt[nk]{a}^{jn}=\sqrt[k]{a}^j=a^{\frac jk}$.  So if $x<y$ then $a^x=\sup\{a^q:q<x\}<\sup\{a^q:q<y\}=a^y$.

Comment: Thank you all. Very much obliged.